# How to use Cl() with character?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I have a list of symbols in a csv file and I want to screen for the ones with closing price higher than 5.

I already ran getSymbols for all items in the csv file.

My test runs into error here. I think it's because Cl() doesn't accept characters as arguments. How can I convert character to xts?

```
> library(quantmod)

> passingset
         V1
1       AAB
2    AAR-UN
3       AAV
4       ABT
5       ABX
       (...)

> class(passingset)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(passingset$V1)
[1] "character"


> #Remove closing price < 5
> for (i in 1:nrow(passingset)){
+   company <- passingset$V1[i]
+   if(Cl(company)[length(Cl(company))] < 5){
+     passingset <- passingset[!(passingset$V1 == company),, drop = FALSE]
+   } else 
+       i = i + 1
+   
+   rm(company)
+ }
**Error in Cl(company) : 
  subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "Close"**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for looping!
Assuming you have read the price series with `getSymbols` as you mentioned above then:

```
# an example set of tickers:
pasingset <- data.frame(V1=c('CWB','EEM','VTI','NAK','GIG'),stringsAsFactors = F)

# this gets you the last closings of your tickers
lastClose <- sapply(pasingset$V1,function(x) xts::last(Cl(get(x))))

# shows the tickers which have a close > 5
pasingset$V1[which(lastClose > 5)]
[1] "CWB" "EEM" "VTI"
```

Comment: @hvollmerier thanks a lot! When I try the second line of your code, it still gives me "Error in get(x) : invalid first argument". Have you encountered this before?

Comment: @hotterthanmath, as the function `last` is used by several packages I can only assume that you may have other packages loaded which use a function by the same name. To make sure to use the the function from the `xts-package`  write `xts::last` instead of `'last` as I have edited. Another possible problem might be that your csv-file does not have the same structure/column names as a downloaded file from yahoo. To check download the exactly same tickers as in my example with `getSymbols` from yahoo. You should not see an error.